# Finding the determinant of an N x N matrix entered as list of lists - "list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, determinants

I'm trying to write a program to find the determinant of an NxN matrix in Python 3.3 but it returns a "list index out of range" error. There is a debugging print statement in the det function which shows that in the case of the 2 x 2 matrix example given then it works fine for the first minor, but then A is reduced to [[3]] and I can't see what part of my code is changing it at all? I want the det function to leave A unchanged as it works along the first row.

```
def minor(matrix,i):
    """Returns the Minor M_0i of matrix"""
    minor = matrix
    del minor[0] #Delete first row
    for b in list(range(len(matrix))): #Delete column i
        del minor[b][i]
    return minor

def det(A):
    """Recursive function to find determinant"""
    if len(A) == 1: #Base case on which recursion ends
        return A[0][0]
    else:
        determinant = 0
        for x in list(range(len(A))): #Iterates along first row finding cofactors
            print("A:", A)
            determinant += A[0][x] * (-1)**(2+x) * det(minor(A,x)) #Adds successive elements times their cofactors
            print("determinant:", determinant)
        return determinant

data = [[4, 3], [6, 3]]

print(det(data))
```

Comment: what's the point of turning your range into a list? ```for x in list(range(len(A)))```

Comment: Does that not make any difference? I've been learning with Python 2.7 (on Codecademy) and I think on there then range() produces a list normally, so I think I felt I had to fix the difference.

Comment: It hurts performance this way. If you're looping over an iterable, any iterable will do, whether or not you materialize it in a list, first. The list thing is really only interesting for ```range``` vs ```xrange```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `minor = matrix` you aren't creating a copy of the matrix, you're just creating a new reference to it. When you next delete a row from `minor` you're also deleting the row from `matrix`.

[`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) will probably do what you need.

Comment: I've changed the first part of the code to:  
    
    `from copy import deepcopy

    def minor(matrix,i):
        """Returns the Minor M_0i of matrix"""
        minor = deepcopy(matrix)
        del minor[0] #Delete first row
        for b in range(len(matrix)-1): #Delete column i
            del minor[b][i]
        return minor`  
    
and it now works for square matrices of any size, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def minor(matrix,i):

    n = len(matrix)
    minor = []
    minor = matrix.copy()
    row = i//n
    col = i%n - 1
    del minor[row] #Delete first row
    for j in list(range(len(minor))): #Delete column i
        recover_row = list(matrix[j])
        del minor[j][col]
        matrix[j] = recover_row
    return minor
```

This was my resolution to preserving the original matrix. Your code helped me a lot when I was trying to figure out an approach! Let's just say that this is a prime case of where for-loops are far better to use than nested while-loops haha

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of "matrix", it should be "minor" here.

```
for b in list(range(len(matrix))): 
    #Delete column i
```